# Plotting a matrix "by parts" in R?

Tags: r, histogram

I have a 50k by 50k square matrix saved to disk in a text file and I would like to produce a simple histogram to see the distribution of the values in the matrix.

Obviously, when I try to load the matrix in R by using `read.table()`, a memory error is encountered as the matrix is too big. Is there anyway I could possibly load smaller submatrices one at a time, but still produce a histogram that considers all the values of the original matrix? I can indeed load smaller submatrices, but I just override the histogram that I had for the last submatrix with the distribution of the new one.

Comment: You could just set up the cut points for your histogram, for each chunk count the number per cut, then loop through saving the counts for each cut. Summarise these and make a simple bar chart

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach. I don't have all the details because you did not provide sample data or the expected output, but one way to do this is through the `read_chunked_csv` function in the readr package. First, you will need to write your summarisation function and then apply this to each chunk. See the below for a full repex.

```
# Call the Required Libraries
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)

# First Generate Some Fake Data
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")

fake_dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000*100), ncol = 100))
write_csv(fake_dat, temp)



# Now write a summarisation function
# This will be applied to each chunk that is read into
# memory
summarise_for_hist <- function(x, pos){
  x %>% 
    mutate(added_bin = cut(V1, breaks = -6:6)) %>% 
    count(added_bin)
}

# Note that I manually set the cutpoints or "breaks"
# argument. You would need to refine this based on your
# data and subject matter expertise

# A

small_read <- read_csv_chunked(temp, # data
                               DataFrameCallback$new(summarise_for_hist),
                               chunk_size = 200 # number of lines to read
                               )
```

Now that we have summarised our data, we can combine and plot it.

```
# Generate our histogram by combining all of the results
# and plotting

small_read %>% 
  group_by(added_bin) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(added_bin, total))+
  geom_col()
```

This will yield the following:

[image]